# PHP Curl - Knowing the Content-type

Tags: php, curl, request-headers

Below is an example without `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`, and it works fine.

```
<?php
$URL = "http://someurl.info"; 
$data = 'x_test_request=0&x_version=3.1&x_delim_data=true&x_relay_response=false';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1800);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
$response = curl_exec($ch);

?>
```

Does Curl auto-detect the type of data we Post, and auto-count the string length?
Or should we always specify Both?

Or does it largely depend on the destination's rules and expectations?

To be safe, I usually add the header info like this:

```
<?php
$contentlen = strlen(trim($data));
$headersARR = array(
        "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "Content-length: ".$contentlen,
        ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headersARR);
?>
```

I read https://www.php.net/curl_setopt, but haven't noticed any details on defaulted content-type parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not specify anything about `Content-type` but use the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` then the header is always `Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as default. Also it sets the `Content-length:` automatically.

For this reason, when we post `JSON` content through the `POST` we need to override the `content-type` through `HTTPHEADER` option. It is similar to `XML` or any other specific type of content.

Comment: that's basically what I expected to hear, but had to ask